# How can I create a .txt file containing data being generated in real-time in Linux terminal when a program is running?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, logs, perl

I am running an AutoDock Vina program (using a Perl script) in Linux. 
It generates lots of important data
(regarding binding free energy of protein-ligand docked complexes). 
However, I cannot save them in a log.txt file (because the current version of Vina has removed the option to create log files for individual docked complexes). 
Since my program will be taking 4-5 days to finish, I wanted to know how I can save this data in real-time inside log.txt files every time it gets generated for each docked complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem well,
but if you can launch your command from terminal,
it is possible to use redirections:

```
./yourprogram > path/to/your/logfile.txt
```

or, if you want to append to an existing file:

```
./yourprogram >> path/to/your/logfile.txt
```

If you need more help, don't hesitate to add some information about how data is generated by your program (terminal output, or any other means...)

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: The program requires running a Perl script. $perl Vina_linux.pl    It will then ask for the input files list from me. How can I modify the command you have provided me above according to this?

Comment: If you need to interact with your script (ie. entering file file name as you said), it is a bit more complex.
I have no idea, maybe modifying your perl script to directly write into a file from the program ?

Comment: Here there is some explanation on how to do that: https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-write-to-file/

Comment: Thank you @thiblcr for your prompt help. I have decided to not use Perl script instead directly used a bash script file and just as you answered before append it to a new log.txt file

Comment: Ok, I'm happy you found a solution, don't hesitate to tell us if it worked as expected. If the answer works for you, mark it as solved ;-)

Comment: Sure! It has worked as expected. Where can I mark my query as solved?

Comment: Here is the procedure ;) https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers